# How to avoid partial coverage with lateinit fields in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an Android service written in Kotlin which I inject using Guice. It has lateinit fields which cannot be null, but they must be lateinit because I cannot use constructor injection.

Something around these lines:

```
class VibrationService : Service() {
    @Inject
    private lateinit var pm: PowerManager
    private lateinit var wakeLock: WakeLock

    override fun onCreate() {
        AlarmApplication.guice().injectMembers(this)
        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "VibrationService")
        wakeLock.acquire()
    }
}
```

Now when I create JaCoCo reports, all lines where any of the lateinit fields are accessed are marked as partially covered. I think Kotlin compiler adds some checks to the bytecode to make sure that fields are initialized before they are accessed.

Is there any way to disable these checks? I want my 100% coverage:-)

Comment: Ok, it seems that I can inject pm with by lazy { guice().getInstance(PowerManager::class.java) }, but in this case wakeLock will still be initlized in onCreate and it cannot be val.

Comment: Yes, the generated bytecode includes checks and calls to various methods in [`kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/runtime.jvm/src/kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.java).
There's no good solution right now, but see [KT-18714](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18714)/[KT-18383](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-18383) and [jacoco/jacoco#552](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/552).

Comment: I have looked in the generated bytecode and I think the issue has to be addressed on the compiler level. Here is the code for lateinit variable:

    ALOAD 0
    GETFIELD com/better/alarm/background/VibrationService.wakeLock : Landroid/os/PowerManager$WakeLock;
    DUP
    IFNONNULL L3
    LDC "wakeLock"
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.throwUninitializedPropertyAccessException (Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L3
    INVOKEVIRTUAL android/os/PowerManager$WakeLock.release ()V
   L4

IFNONNULL is a branch which is not covered by JaCoCo

Comment: This could also be done this way:
    ALOAD 0
    GETFIELD com/better/alarm/background/VibrationService.wl : Landroid/os/PowerManager$WakeLock;
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkLatinitInitilized (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    ALOAD 0
    GETFIELD com/better/alarm/background/VibrationService.wl : Landroid/os/PowerManager$WakeLock;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL android/os/PowerManager$WakeLock.release ()V

Comment: I haven't tried, but ProGuard `-assumenosideeffects` could be used to remove the call. I'm not sure if it would delete the now-emptt branch, or if it stays in the bytecode, and if it does I'm not sure what JaCoCo would do with it.

Comment: This problem also happens for Spring `@Autowired lateinit` variables. Lines of code where the variables are used are marked by JaCoCo as "partially covered by tests" when they should be "fully covered by tests".

Comment: Did any of you figure out a workaround for this? I don't believe this has been resolved yet.

Comment: I have stopped using lateinit in my code almost exclusively. In services I use by inject() or by lazy { }, and everywhere else primary constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the new [kotlinx-kover](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-kover) Gradle plugin which is compatible with JaCoCo and IntelliJ.
It resolves the problem with `inline` functions. Hopefully, it will resolve your problem too.

```kotlin
plugins {
     id("org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kover") version "0.5.0"
}
```

> Once applied, the plugin can be used out of the box without additional configuration.

Watch its [YouTube announcement video](https://youtu.be/jNu5LY9HIbw) and also track its roadmap from [this youtrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49527).

Comment: For Kover 0.4.4 and Kotlin 1.5.0/1.6.0 this is still an issue.
For now I had to get rid of `lateinit` usages in order to get 100% test coverage.
This is an issue of Jacoco (which is used under the hood of Kover).

Comment: I believe this is it - https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/1182