# Kotlin code coverage in CI pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, kotlin, code-coverage

Interested to find code coverage tools for kotlin that work well in a CI pipeline.  use intellij built in code coverage but cant use this in CI. Thanks

Comment: I believe development is happening on various plugins/tools for this. Meanwhile check this: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/gradle-code-coverage-report/390

Answer (score 2):

The Jacoco plugin works fine for coverage of Kotlin code. Configure Jacoco the same as you would for Java.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html

Comment: JaCoCo incorrectly marks some lines as "partially covered by tests". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45525279/how-to-avoid-partial-coverage-with-lateinit-fields-in-kotlin

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new [kotlinx-kover](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-kover) Gradle plugin compatible with JaCoCo and IntelliJ.

```kotlin
plugins {
     id("org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kover") version "0.5.0"
}
```

> Once applied, the plugin can be used out of the box without additional configuration.

Watch its [YouTube announcement video](https://youtu.be/jNu5LY9HIbw) and also track its roadmap from [this youtrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49527).