# Measure test coverage for Kotlin code?

Tags: kotlin, code-coverage

Is there any way to measure test coverage for Kotlin code? Jacoco gives wrong results because can not determine autogenerated code. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Use the new [kotlinx.kover](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-kover) Gradle plugin.

`id("org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kover") version "0.4.1"`

Once applied, the plugin can be used out of the box without additional configuration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin Test Coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48220460/kotlin-test-coverage)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA,this link will be helpful for you:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-coverage-measurement.html

else you can check 'Sonarqube', it is good tools for your purpose and it is easy to use and have a good community.

Comment: Hey Vahid. Welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for your answer. Can you please summarize the instructions from the link in your own words?

Answer (score -2):

Android Studio has came a long way improving it’s capability in unit testing (thought still long way to go I think). Beginning as early as Android Studio 1.2 (if not mistaken), we could also see coverage testing. This could be as simple as a menu click away by right click on the Test Section of your code package, and then select Run ‘Test in…’ with Coverage as shown below. I think this article help you: https://medium.com/@elye.project/making-android-studio-test-coverage-works-with-kotlin-and-robolectric-a2ab12cdd551